# How to color cited references in the bibiliographic part using \eqref{name}?

Tags: cross-referencing, color

How to cite References in the bibiliographic part using `\eqref{name}`?

For example, suppose we have a line as follows:

> Using the works of  [X1]  (**I want to see a blue color box**) , we get

where the reference is

```
\bibitem{X1} B. Dragovich, N. Z. Misic, p-Adic Invariant Summation of Some p-Adic Functional Series, p-Adic Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis and Applications, 2014.
```

I used to `\label{X1}` and using `\eqref{X1}`, I got

> Using the works of (X1) (**just X1 is red color and not obtained 3rd bracket also**)

How to get [X1] with red color box ?

Comment: Do you just want to have the link with a red frame, or also want an additional pair of round brackets around it?

Comment: @Tiuri, I just want a blue color 3rd bracket around  'X1'

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Can you please clarify exactly how the citation should look like: how many brackets of which type (round, square) and of which color?

Comment: @Tiuri, square type

Comment: Hm, I cannot really reconstruct your situation. Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Tiuri, please see the reference citation in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.0918.pdf. with blue color boxes

Comment: Please tell us (a) if you use BibTeX (or some other software tool) to create the formatted bibliographic entries and (b) which bibliography style you employ and whether you use a citation management tool such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: I meant a code example, I know how citations look like. Without a compilable code, I will not be able to help you. However, some guidances: You should really use `\cite` to refer to the bibliography, not `\ref` or `\eqref` - that is most certainly also what was done in the arXiv paper you've linked. And then have a look at the `hyperref` documentation for how to adjust the colors of the links. Again, if you provide a minimal setup that describes what bibliography and citing macros you use, I'm happy to try to add the necessary adjustments there.

Comment: @Mico, I use \begin{thebibiliography}     \bibitem{}   ........     \end{thebibliography}

Comment: I see no blue boxes in the pdf file you provided a link to. I do see light green boxes, though: they enclose alpha-style citation call-outs. Do you want to create green boxes?

Comment: Can you adjust the title of your question?  It seems to me you are asking about how to change the color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\eqref` is not intended to refer to bibliography items, but to equations.  The correct command to refer to bibliography items is `\cite`, the label is provided by the `\bibitem` command, so

```
\bibitem{X1} B. Dragovich...
```

can be cited with

```
\cite{X1}
```

To get colours, the standard apporach is to use the `hyperef` package.  By default citations are coloured green, but you can change this.  To get a blue box, use

```
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=0 0 1}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=0 0 1}

\begin{document}

Using the works of \cite{X1}, we get\dots

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{X1} B. Dragovich, N. Z. Misic, $p$-Adic Invariant Summation of
  Some $p$-Adic Functional Series, $p$-Adic Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis
  and Applications, 2014.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If instead you want blue text, then you can use

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue}
```

[image: sample coloured text]

Alternatively, you can color citations commands without using `hyperef`, as follows

[image: sample with color package]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@cite}[1]{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{#1}}\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Using the works of \cite{X1}, we get\dots

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{X1} B. Dragovich, N. Z. Misic, $p$-Adic Invariant Summation of
  Some $p$-Adic Functional Series, $p$-Adic Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis
  and Applications, 2014.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here I have redefined the printing command for citations, namely `\@cite`, to put the number in a box with a blue border via

```
\renewcommand*{\@cite}[1]{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{#1}}
```

Here `white` is the background color apply, you could change this too if you wished.  I have also changed the printing of the labels in the bibligraphy to match this style by redefining `\@biblabel`.  Note for all this to work, you need to load the `color` package and to enclose the redefinitions in `\makeatletter..\makeatother` (due to the `@` character in the macro names).

Comment: your `\renewcommand`  formula works fine to highlight a color box around the `citation number` e.g., say `\cite{Mat}` but it is not enclosing everything when I need to cite something like `\cite[Theorem~22.3]{Mat} `

Comment: replacing `#1` by `#2` enclose the whole thing. But it shows some error

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Does `\renewcommand*{\@cite}[2]{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{#1, #2}}` do want you want?

Comment: Or rather `\renewcommand*{\@cite}[2]{\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{#1\if@tempswa, #2\fi}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both worked. But the 1st one creating a default comma `'`  (probably coming from `{#1, #2}`) after every citation number. If I delete the `'` of `{#1, #2}` leaving with only `space` then the problem disappear but appears in the citation `\cite[Theorem~22.3]{Mat}` i.e., it shows something like `[4 Theorem. 22.3]` with no comma `'` between the number `4` and the word `Theorem`.

Comment: However the 2nd command you wrote worked nicely without any problem. So I chose the 2nd one

Answer (score 3):

I can see no blue boxes in the pdf file you provided a link to. To create **light-green** boxes, as is one in the pdf file, use `\cite` rather than `\ref` or `\eqref` and load the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\nobreakdash" macro
\newcommand\padic{p\nobreakdash-\kern-1.5ptAdic}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots\ \cite{X1} \dots

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{X1} B. Dragovich, N. Z. Misic, \padic{} Invariant Summation of Some \padic{} 
Functional Series, \padic{} Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis and Applications, 2014.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much